# Copy file to Kubernetes Pod

Tags: python, kubernetes, kubernetes-python-client

I am trying to copy a binary file to Kubernetes pod using the following way. The script work if the file is text format but not for binary.

```
from kubernetes import client, config

try:
    config.load_kube_config()
except TypeError:
    config.load_incluster_config()

api = client.CoreV1Api()

exec_command = ['tar', 'xvf', '-', '-C', '/']
resp = stream(
    api.connect_get_namespaced_pod_exec,
    'pod_name', 'namespace', command=exec_command,
    stderr=True, stdin=True, stdout=True, tty=False, _preload_content=False
)

source_file = './test_data/simulated/some.nc'
destination_path = '/tmp/some.nc'

with TemporaryFile() as tar_buffer:
    with tarfile.open(fileobj=tar_buffer, mode='w') as tar:
        tar.add(name=source_file, arcname=destination_path)
    tar_buffer.seek(0)
    commands = []
    commands.append(tar_buffer.read())

    while resp.is_open():
        resp.update(timeout=1)
        if resp.peek_stdout():
            print("STDOUT: %s" % resp.read_stdout())
        if resp.peek_stderr():
            print("STDERR: %s" % resp.read_stderr())
        if commands:
            c = commands.pop(0)
            resp.write_stdin(str(c))
            # works if source and destination files are txt format
            # and the above line is resp.write_stdin(c.decode())
        else:
            break
    resp.close()
```

On the STDERR I am getting the the following log "tar: This does not look like a tar archive"

Comment: where is the `source_file`? is it somewhere inside the node?

Comment: @KamolHasan yes

Comment: @KamolHasan I have two apps deployed on K8s. The first Django app will generate a dataset (.nc) file if you hit an api endpoint. I need to copy that generated dataset to another app's directory. The second app is basically a dataset watcher. Any changes  (like add/edit/delete of .nc) of files inside a particular directory will start a sequence of calculations.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I find a package that is doing exactly this. My problem was copying binary files. Turns out this package runs a Kubernetes Job to complete the copying.

https://github.com/nuvo/skbn

Comment: Could you elaborate how you did that?
Your code snippet is in python, the package you posted is in go

Comment: The code snippet I posted doesn't work. That's why I used the skbn package and it is working fine. I managed to transfer text files using the above script but not binary or any other format.